# Firebase attribution tracking

Tags: android, firebase, event-tracking, firebase-analytics

I added a few networks for attribution tracking in Attribution->Network Settings and added those network SDKs, but how can I see conversions from specific ad network from Firebase? For example `first_open`.

If I go to Attribution-> click `first_open` -> and then trying to apply filter, there is nothing under `Source`. I suppose there should be my networks, aren't they? How can I see number of installs from specific ad network on Firebase?

Comment: i cant follow the docs on conversions at all. just need to track what site the conversions are coming from. f**k!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing everything correctly -- although you shouldn't even need to apply a filter. At the bottom of the page will be a breakdown of the first_open conversions by source. This, for example, is what you'll see if you look at the [Firebase Demo Project](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7157552?hl=en) at the bottom of the `first_open` report:

[image]

If you're not seeing any data, my recommendation might be to wait a little while; sometimes it takes a bit of time for these reports to follow through. Also, I'm fairly sure these reports aren't retroactive. Once you add a network, you'll see attribution data for those networks moving forward.

Comment: any tutorials on "adding a network" im not sure what these paramaters are? i just want to know if the conversion is coming from. facebook or youtube etc.