# Linking Apple attribution data (iAd) with Firebase conversion tracking

Tags: firebase, iad, firebase-analytics

I've seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610908/firebase-attribution-tracking) but it's a little different as what I need is a bit more in depth than just the channel attribution broadly as what the answer was there.

With iAd you can `requestAttributionDetails` as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iad/setting_up_apple_search_ads_attribution?fbclid=IwAR39jtOh6B651A2CgGApC3WTnCoJggRyiCqhtRmmFLhFWkMq_Nbj3j0uDdk),
Which provides details such as campaign id, keyword, etc.
Firebase collects `in_app_purchase` events automatically ([here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6317485)), but doesn't collect any of that information, at least according to the docs linked.

My question is if the `in_app_purchase` event is automatically recorded by firebase, how do I override it *(or maybe add an additional event or user properties)* to provide my analytics the data it needs of campaign attribution, keyword, etc. derived from this iAd data. These attribution details are vitally important to us to establish which campaigns are giving us what return once users convert.